# When length of edit text increases the listView item outside scrollView disappears in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-studio

Following is my xml code, when i write multiple lines in the edit text the listView which is outside the scrollView  disappears and if i put the listView in scrollView then listview stops scrolling. Please help !

**activity_feedback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_feedback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.hello.FeedbackActivity"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"></include>
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/email_txt_view"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email To:"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_txt_view"
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="guneetk@hkcl.in"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_address"
        android:id="@+id/subject_txt_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Enter email Subject:"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/subject_txt_view"
        android:id="@+id/email_subject"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailSubject"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_subject"
        android:id="@+id/emailBody_txt_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Text:"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/emailBody_txt_view"
        android:id="@+id/email_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_text"
        android:id="@+id/mobile_txt_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Mobile Number:"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/mobile_txt_view"
        android:id="@+id/mobile_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/mobile_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/attachment"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/attachment"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attachment_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/attachment"
            android:text="Attachment"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/attachment"
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/send"
            android:elevation="8dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/attachment_label"
            android:id="@+id/send_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/send"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/filelist"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_feedback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="com.example.android.hello.FeedbackActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email_txt_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Email To:"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email_address"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/email_txt_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:text="guneetk@hkcl.in"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subject_txt_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/email_address"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Enter email Subject:"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_subject"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/subject_txt_view"
                android:inputType="textEmailSubject" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailBody_txt_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/email_subject"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Enter Text:"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/emailBody_txt_view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mobile_txt_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/email_text"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Enter Mobile Number:"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/mobile_txt_view"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/mobile_text"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/attachment"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/attachment" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/attachment_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/attachment"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:text="Attachment"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/send"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/attachment"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/send" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/send_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/send"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/attachment_label"
                    android:text="Send"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```